# Warn questioners about their questions being closed

Tags: feature-request

Now-a-days I see many questions getting closed within moments, without time for OP to understand what's going on and what he should do and most of the time, he is left in disarray and only comes to know what is going on ***after*** the question is closed with the reason stated.

OP doesn't even have the time to edit.

Comments are only added if it's a duplicate or the close reason is "Other". And most of the time, people voting to close don't comment.

I propose adding a alert box on a question with what's going on and what he should do.

Comment: I think question closers should be able to be challenged in the battle arena of Code golf. When I emerge victorious, my beloved question will have FREEDOM!!

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for the user to act quickly and change the question before it is closed. (Put on hold.) No need at all. Getting it closed/on hold is to prevent answers accumulating when it's clear the question needs substantial change.

Once those changes have been made, the question can be reopened. There is no race to get the edits in before the close.

Comment: You're right about OP being able to act after the question's been closed, but why shouldn't they know what's going on before then? And a question that's fundamentally flawed can stay open for hours, days, weeks, even years. During all this time, the user might not even know something is wrong, where-as a notification to start would've told them.

Comment: @Dukeling Not going to argue but that is not this question. The existence of a question that is AWFUL but attracts neither comments nor enough downvotes to get closed and therefore sits there staying awful is not the same as a user getting surprised by a quick close and feeling blindsided.

Comment: No.  The close and reopen idea is fundamentally broken - entirely apart from the adverse psychological effect, it's an absurd waste of everyone's effort to go through the process of closing, and then reopening again when someone is ready to post a meaningful answer to a meaningful question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So we rather have everyone go through the process of reading the question, the comments, the answers, the comments on the answers, all just to figure out what the question is asking, and then possibly have them wait around for ... how long, for the asker to respond? Voting to close / reopen a question takes a few seconds after you've read it (which takes a lot longer), so, proportionally, there isn't a lot of time spent on that.

Comment: Getting it re-opened takes a lot longer than "a few seconds" - the delay to post your answer can be hours or days or *never*.  But I'd support a "some people think this question is unanswerable / you will earn no reputation for answering it" category in place of closing, as bad calls with that aren't an actual impediment to answers from others with more expertise, while those who wish could filter these out of their view of the site.

Answer (score 4):

I have this notification on my codegolf account:

[image]

So, I would like similar kind of box to appear on top of OP's question.

Following are the messages I intend to display

### 1.For dupes:

> It seems that this question may already have a answer.
>
> {Duplicated
>   answer link here}
>
> If any of answers provided in above link, answers your question, then
>   delete this question as many low-quality questions will trigger a
>   [question
>   ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th),
>   else improve your question so that it no longer counts as a duplicate

### 2. For "Unclear about what is being asked":

> It seems that the users who might help you, are finding it difficult
>   to understand your question. Make sure you present your question in an
>   understandable manner, so you'll get your answers. If it isn't
>   corrected, not only this question will be closed but will also
>   increase your chances of getting a [question
>   ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

### 3. For off-topics:

> Your question doesn't seem to belong here. The reason is
>
> {Actual message of highly voted off-topic close reason}
>
> More off-topic questions are a sure way to get a [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) and check out what's on topic on Stack Overflow
>    [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

### 4. For too-broad:

> Your question, most probably won't get answers as there are either too
>   many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this
>   format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an
>   issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
>
> Read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and avoid the [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

### 5. For primarily opinion-based:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise. Your question is one of them. Edit your question to be
>   specific and answerable with facts.
>
> Read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and avoid
>   the [question
>   ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

## Note:

This display can be limited to first 10 - 15 questions per *new* or less than 100 rep OPs. Because if OP has that many answers and is still out of ban, I think it is safe to assume that he is used to, on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: Dupes already have a notice that says "Your question may already be answered here".

Comment: @BoltClock, I knew this was up to and I was editing my question when your comment came.